# PDF to XML for table format using c#

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, pdf-to-html

How to convert a PDF file which contains only tables to a equivalent XML format?

Comment: This question is overly vague. It would probably help if you put an example in as well as the code you've already tried instead of just asking a generic question.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the PDF contains tagged content, there are no table 'structures' in PDF, just text. I wrote a blog post explaining this at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2009/04/pdf-text/